# CORS issue Angular4 & c# web api

Tags: c#, http, cors, http-headers

I have a web API that runs on http://localhost:59543/ for which I have enabled the CORS by adding the following to Web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I have a angular 4 project that run on http://localhost:4200/. I use the following code to make an HTTP request

LoginService

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService extends BaseService {

    request: Http;

    constructor(request: Http) {
        super(request);
        this.request = request;
    }

    postLogin(body: Object): Observable<any> {
        var options = this.options;
        options.method = "POST";
        return this.request.post(AppSettings.apiURL + "api/Login", body, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

Base Service

```
@Injectable()
export class BaseService {

    headers: Headers;
    options: RequestOptions;

    constructor(private http: Http) {

        this.headers = new Headers();

        let token: string = localStorage.getItem("TOKEN");

        if (token != undefined)
            this.headers.append("AUTH_TOKEN", token);

        this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    }

    public extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || {};
    }

    public handleError(error: Response | any) {
        return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
    }

}
```

**Issue**

When I set the header for HTTP request

```
this.headers.append("AUTH_TOKEN", token);
```

I am getting the following error

> api/Login: 1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a
>   status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>
> :4200/#/login:1 Failed to load http://localhost:59543/api/Login:
>   Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405.

But when I remove the header it works. Any advice or guidance would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: 405 means youy didn't authorize your HTTP verb. Said otherwise, you didn't authorize POST requests on your API.

Comment: And as it isn't an Angular issue, I'm going to remove the tag, because no Angular code you write will ever resolve this issue.

Comment: I tought there may be an issue with the angular code as the request works when I remove the header from request. @trichetriche

Comment: As you can see yourself, the request is going well, and your server is answering with an error. If removign a header makes it work, it means your server is badly configured, because either way, Angular has done its job.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction, any suggestions on where to look on server? @trichetriche

Comment: [Start there !](https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-http-methods-correctly-in-asp-net-web-api/)

Comment: The error message in the question indicates the problem method is the OPTIONS method. The server is responding to the CORS preflight OPTIONS request with a 405. That server instead needs to be configured to respond to OPTIONS requests with a 200 and the right CORS response headers.

Answer (score 0):

Your should pass token with token type like,

```
this.headers.append("Authorization", "bearer "+token);
```

Here, bearer is your token type. It would be another which you set is default.